# JSON encode no output

Tags: php, mysql, json, ajax

I've tried to look up different ways to get this json to output correctly but im not sure if im accessing the right variable in php/or the success function value.pTitle as well as how to I get the access to the other value out such as artTitle im failing somewhere not sure where or why.***UPDATE*** fixed the php file added and an array $data[].

this is my php code.

```
$sqlPAQuery = "SELECT pTitle, GROUP_CONCAT(artTitle) AS 
artTitle 
FROM p 
JOIN art ON art.pId = p.pId 
GROUP BY pTitle";

if ($result=mysqli_query($conn,$sqlPAQuery))
{

$data = []; 
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC))
 {
    $data[] = $row;
 }
 echo json_encode($data);
}
```

This is the outcome from the php encode of row:
[{"pTitle":"ent","artTitle":"11,12"},{"pTitle":"pro","artTitle":"10"},{"pTitle":"sports","artTitle":"1,13"}]

This is the html code:

```
<h3>Output: </h3>
<div id="output"></div>


<script id="source" language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$.ajax({ 
type: "POST",   
  url: 'Data.php',                            
  data: "",                        
  dataType: 'json',                      
  success: function(data)          
  {
  $.each(data, function(index, value) {
     var pageTitle = value.pTitle;           //get name

   $('#output').append("<b>pageTitle: </b>"+pageTitle+"<br/>");
  } 
});
});
```

Output should be:

**pageTitle:** ent

**pageTitle:** pro

**pageTitle:** sport

FIXED THE PHP FILE WORKS

Comment: OK, and what *is* actually happening?

Comment: I think he encode every single result of his query instead of encode an array and try to create a json with a string....

Comment: I was misinformed thinking that $row from the php was an array so the output incorrect from the php file

Answer (score 1):

If you want to proces the json like that this is what you need to do:

```
    if ($result=mysqli_query($conn,$sqlPAQuery)) {
        $data = []; 
        while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC))
        {
            $data[] = $row;
        }
        echo json_encode($data);
    }
```

Comment: I was misinformed thinking that $row from the php file was an array so the output was incorrect from the php file. I thought It was the array because of what json accepts. Thank you for your expertise sieste85